# Why are bullets not appearing on posts?

Tags: html, css, xml

In my this post http://technopcarea.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-make-your-websites-design.html,the bullets are not appearing inspite of addng correct html,why ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please refer to this post before asking
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List type none is added to the ul .

Add list-style-type as css property to ul:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:circle !important">
<li><span style="font-size: large;"><b>Go to Template tab of your blog's HTML</b></span></li>
<li><span style="font-size: large;"><b>Click on Edit HTML button</b></span></li>
<li><span style="font-size: large;"><b>Search For&nbsp;&nbsp;]]&gt;&lt;/b:skin&gt;</b></span></li>
<li><span style="font-size: large;"><b>Add the following piece of codes before it</b></span></li>
</ul>
```

You can add any desired value to list as can be read in following link:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

---

I have checked the link you have provided and in that link you have given a css which has made padding:0 on this list items **li tag**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
border: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Remove this padding and your list style would come as it requires a padding on the content and you have made a padding 0 on li

[image]

Comment: I have done,this nothing is happening.I don't want to add disc style,you understood wrong,my question is that despite of adding the <ul> tag bullets are not appearing why ? and any suggestions

Comment: i have edited my answer check this now!

Comment: I removed the li from that,but still it is not appearing

Comment: i am adding the image to the answer try and understand from that.

Comment: I did what you said,thanks you mate it worker,very much thank you.